# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /gigs/2/status Couldn't find Gig with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a route to the default restful routes in my app,so in my controller I have an action called status, it's verb is Patch, but I get the above error each time I try to update an attribute via the status action, Note: the default update action in the Restful route has no issues.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :projects do
    resources :gigs, shallow: true do
        patch :status
    end
  end
end
```

Gigs Controller

```
class GigsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gig, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,:status]

  def status
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gig.update(:done, true)
        format.html { redirect_to @gig, notice: 'Gig was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gig }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gig.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_gig         
      @gig = Gig.find(params[:id])
    end

    def gig_params
      params.require(:gig).permit(:name, :description, :done,:timeline)
    end
end
```

and here is the link I added to the `index.html.erb` to execute the update

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Mark as Done', gig_status_path(gig), method: :patch %></td>
```

Here is the log

```
Started PATCH "/gigs/2/status" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-07 12:26:20 +0100
Processing by GigsController#status as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"iNYFcsiwtNnCAC9goTGtfrqHFnBKufpgQ+61/pwZLVV6Nw82MBTART5ozVQUVsk74UFiWDknWrtoqYLN9D/2YQ==", "gig_id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mGig Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "gigs".* FROM "gigs" WHERE "gigs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Gig with 'id'=:
  app/controllers/gigs_controller.rb:93:in `set_gig'

Started POST "/__better_errors/df8ad027b952f89c/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-07 12:26:20 +0100
```

Comment: What's `gig` in `gig_status_path(gig)`?

Comment: thats the id, the link works great, the error seems to be coming from the status action,i just can't figure it out yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check URI Pattern by using command `rake routes` for status action.

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
     gig_status PATCH  /gigs/:gig_id/status(.:format)           gigs#status
   project_gigs GET    /projects/:project_id/gigs(.:format)     gigs#index
                POST   /projects/:project_id/gigs(.:format)     gigs#create
new_project_gig GET    /projects/:project_id/gigs/new(.:format) gigs#new
       edit_gig GET    /gigs/:id/edit(.:format)                 gigs#edit
            gig GET    /gigs/:id(.:format)                      gigs#show
                PATCH  /gigs/:id(.:format)                      gigs#update
                PUT    /gigs/:id(.:format)                      gigs#update
```

so you need to use `gig_id` in case of status action

Modify method `set_gig` as follows:

```
   def set_gig
      @gig = Gig.find(params[:gig_id])
    end
```